# Unable to connect Odoo pod with postgres pod in private GKE

Tags: postgresql, odoo, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy odoo docker image (with postgres database dependency) on private GKE. But I have problem while connecting this pods. I have tried to open port but it seems reach dead end.
This docker images I am using to deploy on private gke - https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo
Any help in this will be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Private GKE means that you have an VPS there. Install Odoo in that VPS and config to run with your custom module in the addons_path so you could get it installed. Make sure the ports (default 8069) are open on which Odoo is running, by check in the firewall rules and add the rules for your port or ports. Use the following URL as a guide to do it:

[Firewall rules in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)

I hope this is useful for you.

Regards.

Comment: I have tried that but problem is still there! Can you please suggest any reference document or steps to make it simple ?

Comment: postgres  
Does not have minimum availability - this is error appearing after exposing odoo port 8069!

Comment: kubectl logs postgres-596c9cc7df-9826x
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

       See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
       https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html